# Changing contents of a table to verbatim

Tags: tables, fonts

As per title, I would like the text in a specific table to be written in verbatim.

Being able to change the font of specific rows in a table would be a bonus.

Currently what I have is as follows:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\fontsize{11}{9}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| l |  l | l | l |} 
\hline
\hline\hline 
Parse subtree    & String & Semantics & Agreement Features  \\ [0.7ex] 
%heading
\hline
np(noun(brad))    & brad&  [brad]  &  [masculin,singular]\\ 
verb(saves)     &  saves&  [Y,X,saves(X,Y)] &  \\
np(det(a),n(life))  & a life & [a(Z),life(Z)]  & [singular] \\
vp(v(saves),np(det(a),n(life)) & saves a life& ? & \\ [1ex] 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: `verbatim` environment works in a `tabular`

Comment: What is the final goal? Do you want to show the code for a table and its result side by side?

Comment: Not really. The table is filled with some small code segments. Honestly it's only for cosmetics. Anyhow, ultimately I want all the text in verbatim except the first row.

Comment: Your example doesn't have any `\ ` so you don't seem to need verbatim, only `\texttt` (verbatim is tricky if you want `&` to separate the cells as normally verbatim makes that a normal character). Also please always post complete documents not just fragments.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion, that definitively solves my problem. Wish you had typed it as a candidate answer so that I could vote it as the best response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest, you use the `array` package, to get the possibility of specifying macros to be expanded before the content of any table cell, e.g.

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\macros}c}
```

## Your example

I tuned the layout a little by using the `booktabs` package for pretty table rules.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\ttfamily}{l}l>{\ttfamily}{l}>{\ttfamily}{l}} 
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Parse subtree} & String       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Semantics} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Agreement Features} \\
    \midrule
    np(noun(brad))                    & brad         & [brad]                        & [masculin,singular]                    \\
    verb(saves)                       & saves        & [Y,X,saves(X,Y)]              &                                        \\
    np(det(a),n(life))                & a life       & [a(Z),life(Z)]                & [singular]                             \\
    vp(v(saves),np(det(a),n(life))    & saves a life & ?                             &                                        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image]